# grid overlay showing up as soon a i launch chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools

for some reason as soon as i launch chrome developer tools i get a grid overlay.. as depicted:

[image]

I tried uninstalling all the unnecessary chrome apps (that may be causing this).. and restarted chrome, but the grid still shows up.

Interestingly, as soon as I close google dev tools the grid disappears.. so it must be a behavior related to dev tools.. How Do I turn it off?

Comment: Does this only occur on tiled map displays , made up of many smaller pictures that form a grid that looks just like that?

Comment: that's totally coincidental.. this grid also happens in non-map pages as well.. thanks for raising that point..

Comment: but let me also add that i noticed these grids only happen on experimental pages (ie a small site i'm running out of my localhost).. both angular apps as well

Answer (score 3):

turns out to be an option in chrome dev tools i turned on by mistake under `rendering`: show composited layer borders:

[image]

checking it off solved the problem